# jq: How to combine disjoint object values as a single object of key/value pairs?

Tags: json, jq

If I have a JSON input data:

**input.json**

```
{
   "metadata": {
      "guid": "07f90eed-105d-41b2-bc20-4c20dfb51653"
   },
   "entity": {
      "name": "first"
   }
}
{
   "metadata": {
      "guid": "da187e3a-8db9-49fd-8c05-41f29cf87f51"
   },
   "entity": {
      "name": "second"
   }
}
{
   "metadata": {
      "guid": "6685c3af-5427-4add-8764-7b18ae3c23bb"
   },
   "entity": {
      "name": "third"
   }
}
```

and I want to create from it the following:

```
{
  "first": "07f90eed-105d-41b2-bc20-4c20dfb51653",
  "second": "da187e3a-8db9-49fd-8c05-41f29cf87f51",
  "third": "6685c3af-5427-4add-8764-7b18ae3c23bb"
}
```

That is, the input data is a collection of separate JSON objects, each of which has the structure shown. I want the output to be a single JSON object where the key is the `.entity.name` and the value is the `.metadata.guid`.

I have tried:

```
jq -r '{.entity.name: .metadata.guid}' input.json
jq -r 'map({(.entity.name): .metadata.guid})' input.json
```

but these just yields a syntax error. The closest I got was:

```
jq -r '.entity.name as $name|.metadata.guid as $guid | { ($name) : ($guid) }' input.json
{
  "first": "07f90eed-105d-41b2-bc20-4c20dfb51653"
}
{
  "second": "da187e3a-8db9-49fd-8c05-41f29cf87f51"
}
{
  "third": "6685c3af-5427-4add-8764-7b18ae3c23bb"
}
```

But, the there are still 3 objects (not 1).

I did get one form to give me what I want, but I suspect there is an easier way to do this:

```
jq -r '.entity.name as $name|.metadata.guid as $guid | { ($name) : ($guid) }' input.json | jq -s add
{
  "first": "07f90eed-105d-41b2-bc20-4c20dfb51653",
  "second": "da187e3a-8db9-49fd-8c05-41f29cf87f51",
  "third": "6685c3af-5427-4add-8764-7b18ae3c23bb"
}
```

Any thoughts how how to do this properly?

Comment: Shouldn't it be an array of object ? Looks like invalid JSON

Comment: jq handles disjoint objects just fine. It's not a single JSON object/array/string, etc., but jq doesn't require that it operate on just a single entity.

Comment: A simpler way to get three objects is `jq '{(.entity.name): .metadata.guid}' input.json`. Wrapping `.entity.name` into parentheses tells `jq` to evaluate it as an expression, not as a string.

Answer (score 6):

With single **`jq`** command:

```
jq -s '[.[] | { (.entity.name): .metadata.guid }] | add' input.json
```

- `-s` (`--slurp`) - instead of running the filter for each JSON object in the input, read the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once.

---

The output:

```
{
  "first": "07f90eed-105d-41b2-bc20-4c20dfb51653",
  "second": "da187e3a-8db9-49fd-8c05-41f29cf87f51",
  "third": "6685c3af-5427-4add-8764-7b18ae3c23bb"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to get three objects is `jq '{(.entity.name): .metadata.guid}' input.json`.

Wrapping the key (`.entity.name`) into parentheses tells `jq` to [evaluate it as an expression](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D), not as a string.

This leads to a simpler form of what you already have (using two invocations of `jq`):

```
$ jq '{(.entity.name): .metadata.guid}' input.json | jq -s add
{
  "first": "07f90eed-105d-41b2-bc20-4c20dfb51653",
  "second": "da187e3a-8db9-49fd-8c05-41f29cf87f51",
  "third": "6685c3af-5427-4add-8764-7b18ae3c23bb"
}
```

Comment: This has the potentially RAM-saving merit of postponing the “slurping”.